# How to work with AST with Cofree annotation?

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, comonad, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I have this simple `Expr` AST and I can easily convert it to `String`.

```
import Prelude hiding (Foldable)
import qualified Prelude
import Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Comonad.Cofree

data ExprF r = Const Int
              | Add   r r
                deriving ( Show, Eq, Ord, Functor, Prelude.Foldable )

type Expr = Fix ExprF

testExpr = Fix $ Add (Fix (Const 1)) (Fix (Const 2))

convertToString :: Expr -> String
convertToString = cata $ \case
  e@(Const x) -> show x
  e@(Add x y) -> unwords [x, "+", y]
```

Now I want to add an additional data to it.
So I am trying to use `Cofree`

```
type LineNumber = Int
type Expr2 = Cofree ExprF LineNumber
```

I can convert `Expr` to `Expr2`

```
addLineNumbers :: Expr -> Expr2
addLineNumbers = cata $ \case
  e@(Const _) -> 1 :< e
  e -> 2 :< e
```

But I cannot figure out how to convert `Expr2` to `String`

```
convertToString2 :: Expr2 -> String
convertToString2 = cata $ \case
  e@(_ :< (Const x)) -> show x
  e@(_ :< (Add x y)) -> unwords [x, "+", y]
```

Also, is Cofree the best way to solve this annotation problem?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have an answer for you right now but I will share this thought. `Free` is inductive and `Cofree` is coinductive. That is, _tearing down_ a (well-behaved) free monad using a (total) algebra for an arbitrary functor is guaranteed terminating, and _building up_ a cofree comonad using a coalgebra is guaranteed productive. The other way round is not true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative way of annotating your syntax tree is to compose the annotation into the base functor.

```
-- constant functor
newtype K c a = K c
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

-- functor product
data (f :*: g) a = (:*:) { left :: f a, right :: g a }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

We're going to use the functor product to attach an annotation (inside a `K`) to each layer of the tree.

```
type AnnExpr = Fix (K LineNumber :*: ExprF)
```

If you can generate annotations while only inspecting a single layer of the tree (that is, your annotation-generating code can be expressed as a natural transformation) then you can use the following bit of machinery to modify the functor while keeping the fixpoint structure in place:

```
hoistFix :: Functor f => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Fix f -> Fix g
hoistFix f = Fix . f . fmap (hoistFix f) . unFix
```

This is of limited usefulness, though, as most interesting annotations such as type-checking require traversal of the syntax tree.

You can reuse the code to tear down an `Expr` by simply ignoring the annotations. Given an algebra for `ExprF`...

```
-- instructions for a stack machine
data Inst = PUSH Int | ADD
type Prog = [Inst]

compile_ :: ExprF Prog -> Prog
compile_ (Const x) = [PUSH x]
compile_ (Add x y) = x ++ y ++ [ADD]
```

... you can use it to tear down either an `Expr` or an `AnnExpr`:

```
compileE :: Expr -> Prog 
compileE = cata compile_

compileA :: AnnExpr -> Prog
compileA = cata (compile_ . right)
```

Comment: When you encounter this pattern often, it becomes useful to define such a constant annotation directly: `data (:&) x f a = x :& f a` - this is just a matter of preference, of course.

Comment: @user2407038 I prefer to reuse smaller bits like `K` and `:*:`, and define type/pattern synonyms for doman-specific uses. `type (x :& g) = K x :*: g` and `pattern x :& y = K x :*: y`

Comment: Why doesn't this work with the original `Cofree` type for annotation? (Or does it?)